# Find and graph image, expressed in cartesian, of vector function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, curves

I have the following vector function $\vec{g}:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3/\vec{g} (t) = (cos(t),sin(t),3t)$ and I have to find its image and express it in cartesian form. What I did is:
$$x=cos(t)$$
$$y=sin(t)$$
$$z=3t$$
Then $$x^2 + y^2=1$$ and 
$$z=3arcsin(y)$$
So my answer is $Im(\vec{g})=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3/x^2+y^2=1, z=3arcsin(y) \}$. I think so far I'm correct but I have no idea how to graph such a set, so I'm guessing my solution for $z$ isn't a good one? Intuitively this seems to be some sort of spiral.

Basically my question is whether I should be able to  graph this set as presented or is there a better solution that makes the graphing easier?

Comment: It is an helix with axis Oz.